# EF Fluent API map 0..1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, fluent

Hi guys I have a question about EF Fluent API (Code First :P). In my model I have

```
public class TABLE_A
{
   public virtual long Id {get; set;}
   .... 
   public virtual TABLE_B MyTableBRef {get; set;}
}


public class TABLE_B
{
   public virtual long Id {get; set;}
   .... 
   public virtual TABLE_A MyTableARef {get; set;}
}
```

How am I supposed to map a 0..1 to 0..1 relationship?

In the database on TABLE_B I have a column (FK) that references the PK of TABLE_A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have navigational properties on both sides if you are using a column other than the PK of `TABLE_B`.

```
public class TABLE_A
{
   public virtual long Id {get; set;}
}


public class TABLE_B
{
   public virtual long Id {get; set;}
   .... 
   public virutal TABLE_A MyTableARef {get; set;}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TABLE_A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TABLE_B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TABLE_B>()
           .HasRequired(b => b.MyTableARef)
           .WithMany()
           .Map(b => b.MapKey("FK_Column_name));
    }
}
```

If the PK of `TABLE_B` is also a FK to `TABLE_A` then you can use shared PK mapping with navigational properties on both sides.

**Edit:**

You can use Shared PK mapping as follows

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TABLE_B>()
       .HasRequired(b => b.MyTableARef)
       .WithOptional(a => a.MyTableBRef);
}
```

The `Id` of `TABLE_B` is also an FK to `TABLE_A`.

Comment: I understand .. but if you use the DBFirst emdx I can configure the interface to 0 .. 1 to 0 .. 1 and entities have navigation properties on both.

the database is in the column FK TABLE_A (using DBFirst tables are equal)

how do I using PK shared with navigational mapping properties on Both Sides.

Comment: how does "HasRequired" and "WithMany" fit for the question for relation 0..1 to 0..1?